# Next js with SocketIo, connection is showing 308 and 404 status when deployed through vercel

Tags: next.js, socket.io, cors

I am using socket.io in next js and fetching the same through api to connect in the frontend.

```
import { Server } from "socket.io";

const ioHandler = (req, res) => {
  if (!res.socket.server.io) {
    console.log("*First use, starting socket.io");

    const io = new Server(
      res.socket.server,
      { path: "/api/socket" },
      {
        cors: {
          origin: "https://lets-chat-jet.vercel.app/",
        },
      }
    );

    io.on("connection", (socket) => {
      socket.broadcast.emit("a user connected");
      socket.on("hello", (msg) => {
        socket.emit("hello", "world!");
      });
    });

    res.socket.server.io = io;
  } else {
    console.log("socket.io already running");
  }
  res.end();
};

export const config = {
  api: {
    bodyParser: false,
  },
};

export default ioHandler;
```

here is the client side

```
import { useEffect } from 'react'
import io from 'socket.io-client'

const Socketio = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api/socketio').finally(() => {
      const socket = io()

      socket.on('connect', () => {
        console.log('connect')
        socket.emit('hello')
      })

      socket.on('hello', data => {
        console.log('hello', data)
      })

      socket.on('a user connected', () => {
        console.log('a user connected')
      })

      socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log('disconnect')
      })
    })
  }, []) // Added [] as useEffect filter so it will be executed only once, when component is mounted

  return <h1>Socket.io</h1>
}
export default Socketio
```

I am getting 308 and 404 error when deployed through vercel, though it is working completely fine in local.
Have gone through different approach to solve it.Have used cors, have used cors option whle connecting etc
Please explain why the client is not connecting and make recommendations to fix the issue.when deployed

Comment: In your server-side code you are providing socket.io assets such as socket.io-client.js from the path `/api/socket`, you need to provide the same path on while establishing client connections. Could you replace line `const socket = io()` to `const socket = io('/', { path: '/api/socket' })`. Make sure that '/' is where your socket.io server url.

Answer (score 1):

Vercel is a serverless platform, and it won't support the pure Websockets (Socket.IO) implementation by design. Serverless functions will have maximum execution limits, so they can't maintain a websocket connection for long durations.

You can check the official documentation here.
https://vercel.com/guides/do-vercel-serverless-functions-support-websocket-connections  
https://vercel.com/guides/publish-and-subscribe-to-realtime-data-on-vercel

I had faced the same issue on Vercel and Netlify as well.

Alternative solutions,

1. Host your full Next.js app on a hosting platform where they provide managed
   traditional Node.js-based servers, such as https://render.com/. (I personally hosted a nextjs13+socketio project here: https://github.com/avinashcodelabs/poker-plan-app.)
2. Instead of using Socket.IO directly in your app, use real-time communication providers like Supabase, Firebase, and so on.
3. Separate the socket.io server code to node/express based server app from your nextjs app, host it on any managed traditional server, and host the client code only (the nextjs app) on Vercel.

The complete list of managed tradtional servers availabe for Next.js app deplyoment is documented here - https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying#other-services

I hope this helps.